# Sequelize query get all data between start and enddate

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to query a database with Sequelize to get items that were created between a certain date range. I used the $between operator but I don't seem to be getting anything. it should get all data from the given start and endDate

I tried

```
where: {
  createdAt: {
    [Op.between]: [startDate, endDate]
  }
}
```

like

```
[Op.between]: ["2018-07-08T14:06:48.000Z", "2019-10-08T22:33:54.000Z"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format is wrong, timezone is not needed, try this format

```
[Op.between]: ["2018-07-08 14:06:48.000", "2019-10-08 22:33:54.000"]
```

it should work

Comment: yeah that is just an example , the variable startDate and endDate has no timezone Sir